How to make htaccess code work with parameters

Hi all


I am editing a htaccess file
My url is is cricf.com cricket-article?cardid=3730
I use the code below for rewriting the URL
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} cricket-article.php
RewriteRule (.*).php$ /$1 [L,R]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f
RewriteRule cricket-article cricket-article.php [L]

It's working. But I can't find
ow to make the URL like the example below with this code.
cricf.com/cricket-article/cardid/3730
Can anyone help me?

This question is similar to: Reference: mod_rewrite, URL rewriting and "pretty links" explained. If you believe it’s different, please [edit] the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

With your shown samples please try following. Make sure to clean your browser cache before testing.
RewriteEngine ON

##Using THE_REQUEST for catching references and using them later on.
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \s/(cricket-article)/(cardid)=(\d+)\s [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /%1/%2/%3? [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(cricket-article)/(cardid)/(\d+)/?$ $1.php?$2=$3 [QSA,NC,L]


Thank Ravinder for your response.. I am use this code but It's gives on url bar
cricf.com/cricket-article.php?cardid=3730
When I do some changes like below It gives on url bar
cricf.com/cricket-article/cardid/3730/
But with page not found 404 error
RewriteEngine on RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} /cricket-article.php?cardid=([^\s&]+) [NC]
RewriteRule ^ cricket-article/cardid/%1? [R=302,L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f RewriteRule ^cricket-article/cardid/([^/]+)/?$ cricket-article.php?cardid=$1 [L,QSA,NC]
Any Suggestions..

is your php file and htaccess present on same path?

Hi Ravinder... Yes cricket-article.php  and htaccess both are located in public_html folder on server.
